# Java code to copy all the text while converting upper case letters from one text file to lower case letters in another text file

Tags: java

I am having problem with the code that I wrote to convert upper case letters from one file to lower case letters in another. When the code is run for some text file named inputtext.txt it creates the output file but the upper case text aren't being converted.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TextFile {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Assume default encoding.
         // The name of the file to open for reading.
            File filein = new File("inputtext.txt");
         // The name of the file to open for writing.
            File fileout = new File("outputtext.txt"); 
            char CharCounter = 0;       
            BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filein)));
            PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileout)));

            int z;
            while ((z = in.read()) != -1){

                if (Character.isUpperCase(z)){
                    Character.toLowerCase(z);

                }
                out.write(z);


            }
            // Always close files.
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: **Character.toLowerCase(int)** actually **returns** something too, and this is not C/C++ we are talking here, where you would expect methods to change the value of **primitive types**

Comment: read line by line and call String.toLowerCase on your line before writing it to output file.

Comment: please elaboraten as I am quite new to java and programming as such @ShayHAned

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line and then covert to lower case while writing.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("a")));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("b")));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        pw.write(line.toLowerCase());
    }
    pw.close();
    br.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but could you also point out to me the problem with the code that I wrote.Thanks

Comment: Character.toLowerCase() would actually return the lower cased value. You are not storing/using that value. Rather you are writing the variable z to the output file, which can be in anycase.

Comment: In case you want to your own code write `z= Character.toLowerCase(z);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Problem is **Character.toLowerCase(z)** DOES NOT CONVERT THE VALUE OF **z**, rather returns you a new value, which is the lower case of the variable **z**

```
int theLowerCaseOfZ = Character.toLowerCase(z);
```

And you could easily kill your problem by this

```
int z;
            while ((z = in.read()) != -1){

                if (Character.isUpperCase(z)){ 
                    // SMOKING GUN!!!
                    out.write( (int) Character.toLowerCase(z) );

                }

            }
            // Always close files.
            in.close();
            out.close()
```

And you could also do

```
int theLowerCaseOfZ = (int) Character.toLowerCase(z);
out.write(theLowerCaseOfZ);
```

With all love **RANA SAHIB** :) , **Rachit's** answer is useful too, and I am open to further clarification if needed